# Model Training: naming scheme for saved models with different hyperparameters

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-s3, neural-network, model, pytorch

For a classification task, I've been experimenting with different neural network architectures and training methods: varying the number of hidden layers, activation functions, batch size, epochs, loss function, etc.

Sometimes, I'll want to compare the performance of different models. After training/validation, each model is saved in S3, with a name that indicates its parameters + hyperparameters (e.g. '100_1000_0.5_100_..._1.model')

This naming scheme is messy, and I'd like to find a better way to save/load models based on the (hyper)parameters. One potential alternative is to create nested folders for different arguments (e.g. 100 -> 1000 -> 0.5 -> 100 -> ... -> 1.model) But this convention is still brittle — if I change the number/order of hyperparameters, I've got to reorganize the entire folder structure in S3.

Any suggestions on how to store networks with 10-15 different parameters? (Also, is it even worth storing multiple copies of the same model, trained with different hyperparameters?)

Comment: Im not sure, what your question is (2 possibilities..).
1. You can store the nets using torch.save
2. You could save them using an index and add an additional file where you specify the hyperparametes used for each index

Comment: Possibility #2 answers my question — the additional file can keep track of the parameters used to train each model. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

bene's suggestion was helpful: save each model in a flat directory, with an additional reference file to store the hyperparameters used for each training instance.